# WebView component gives an error (Webpage not available) when navigating to a page whose URL begins with something other than http:// or https://

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

My Android app uses a WebView to let the user navigate around the Internet, but occasionally it encounters a site that navigates using its own funky schema. For example, if you search for "aliexpress", the app will take you to the site's Home page just fine.
[image]

However, if you select any of the buttons on the top, WebView throws an error:

[image]

Comment: I have a webview based App and try it on, things works smoothly. Did you use "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" function?

Comment: Yes and that was the solution (sorry, I should have posted it earlier, but  I've been in a rush to get the product out). Thanks for the suggestion, even though I discovered it independently. I wish I could give you the points for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was call shouldOverrideUrlLoading() as follows:

```
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
              Uri current_page = request.getUrl();
              if (!current_page.toString().startsWith(("http://")) && !current_page.toString().startsWith(("https://"))) return true;
              return false;
            }
```